# iOS Animation Performance

Tags: objective-c, ios, performance, core-animation

I have a game with a number of animated "monsters". The animation is made with ~20 png images for each monster. So I use `UIImageView` with setted `animationImages:`.

The problem is that sometimes there can be a lot of monsters on the screen (up to 110 in total and up to 10 different). So when all of them are on the screen at the same time - I see animation problems (very low fps).

Please, can you give me some advice - how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CoreAnimation` as described in [this](http://mysterycoconut.com/blog/2011/01/cag1/) tutorial. It explains pretty well all the techniques you can use to increase the performance from where you are now (first of all it doesn't use `UIViews` and the standard `animationImages`, second it makes use of sprites (also called texture atlases) which will not only increase performance but also will make your life a lot more easier when it comes to managing the image resources).

Also you can use [CADisplayLink](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) to create a `game loop` in which you can make all the updates. There are several questions/answers here on SO that describe just that.

Comment: Use of CoreAnimation will not solve CPU usage issues, to do that you will need to decode your PNG images to disk before hand. Then, load the already decoded pixel data directly from disk so as to limit CPU usage. If you have lots and lots of animations going at once then this is how you can make them smooth and flicker free.